# Performance of Array.flat() vs spread operator to flatten multiple arrays into one

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, performance

Which is a better and more efficient way to flatten multiple arrays into one?

Spread operator:

```
let arr = [];
for (const array of arrays) {
  arr.push(…array);
}
```

Or with `.flat()`:

```
let arr = [];
for (const array of arrays) {
  arr.push(array);
}
arr = arr.flat();
```

I am using a loop instead of just `const arr = arrays.flat()` because I want to test something very specific.

Comment: You have to test it, but I guess `.flat()` is more efficient as it's implemented by the browser, thus written in C/C++ and better optimized.

Comment: why not just `const arr = arrays.flat()`? No need for your loop (which should be lowercase `for`).

Comment: @plichard l’m from mobile, that’s why I got “for” with upper case.. And I wanted to test something very specific, that’s why I want it with for loop.

Comment: `... ` spreads one level only. It has a different purpose from `Array.prototype.flat`

Comment: @pilchard Surprisingly, according to JSBench, that's slower than the spread.

Comment: `flat` flattens to arbitrary depth. `... ` does does something completely different. Performance is irrelevant when comparing operations that are not analogous

Comment: If I want to run it in server-side, Is there really a difference between the different implementations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need single-level flattening, [according to this JSBench I cooked up](https://jsbench.me/o8kqzo8olz/1),

```
let arr = [].concat(...arrays);
```

is by far the fastest (on my Windows Chrome 93, according to comments not so on Safari), more than 3x the speed of your implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the in-depth answer! If I want to run it in server-side, Is there really a difference between the different implementations?

Comment: If you're running server-side, you're probably using Node.js, which uses the V8 runtime, which is what Chrome uses. The above would probably be fastest there.

Comment: I wasn't expecting such a gap but it looks like `let arr = [...arrays]` is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Running the same bench as the accepted answer, that solution is faster than the others tested, but I tested a couple of others and found another solution that is around ~12% faster:

```js
let arr = [].concat.apply([], arrays);
```

Benchmark testing: https://jsbench.me/adlib26t2y/2